# IntPtr vs UIntPtr

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

This should be simple: I see everywhere people use `IntPtr`, is there any reason I should use `UIntPtr` instead?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know there was an `UIntPtr`. Can we nominate it for the most useless feature of `.NET`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't seem like there would be a good reason to.  From the docs:

> **Remarks**
>
> ...
>
> The IntPtr type is CLS-compliant,
>   while the UIntPtr type is not. ***Only
>   the IntPtr type is used in the common
>   language runtime***. The UIntPtr type is
>   provided mostly to maintain
>   architectural symmetry with the IntPtr
>   type.

Comment: This answer is marked correct while being incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

Well [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr(VS.71).aspx) `UIntPtr` is provided mostly for architectural symmetry.  Another interesting point is that `UIntPtr` is not CLS compliant.

On the surface it would seem that IntPtr is the preferred option.  However, if you know you will be doing pointer arithmetic then UIntPtr may be a better choice since in the off chance there were some obscure problem dealing with negative values.

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference.. For example, on a 32-bit application, new `UIntPtr(0xC01E0001)` results in a pointer at 3223191553, but `IntPtr(0xC01E0001)` results in a System.OverflowException: "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow". That is, because 0xC01E0001 is greater than MaxValue for Int32.

So if one still wants such a pointer, a negative integer needs to be used as internal value for IntPtr, like

```
unchecked((IntPtr)(int)0xC01E0001)
```

To answer your question: For values greater than Int32.MaxValue it is easier and somehow cleaner to use UIntPtr. It is probably always the best solution, since pointers are always considered unsigned.

Comment: Can't reproduce OverflowException by `var p1 = new IntPtr(0xC01E0001); var p2 = (IntPtr)0xC01E0001;`

Comment: @ChrisXue That's probably because you are using a 64-bit architecture, while I was using only 32-bit. So, essentially, I used Int32, you used Int64. To produce an overflow, you need bigger numbers. I've edited my answer.